# The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ? my code is running none stop

Tags: python

```
num = 600851475143

New_list = range(num + 1)

check =0

list_appender = []

for i in New_list:

    num1 = num / New_list

    finder = num1 % 2

    print(finder)

    if finder == 1 :

        list_appender.append(num1)

    check = check + 1



List_down = len(list_appender)

list_appender.pop(len(list_appender) - 1)

List_down = len(list_appender)


list_up = 0

NewNumAppender = []

for i in list_appender:

    Divider1 = list_appender[list_up]

    Divider2 = list_appender[List_down -1]

    NewNum = Divider1 % Divider2

    NewNumDivder = NewNum % 2

    if NewNumDivder == 1:

        NewNumAppender.append(NewNum)

    List_down = List_down - 1

    list_up = list_up + 1




List_down = len(NewNumAppender)


list_up = 0
lll = []
for i in NewNumAppender:

    Divider1 = NewNumAppender[list_up]

    Divider2 = NewNumAppender[List_down -1]

    NewNum = Divider1 % Divider2

    NewNumDivder = NewNum % 2

    if NewNumDivder == 1:
        lll.append(NewNum)

    List_down = List_down - 1
    list_up = list_up + 1

try:
    lll.pop(0)
    print(lll)
except:
    print("Number Is a prime")
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  If yes, what have you found?  Where do you believe the issue to originate?  Once the origin is found, how can we help? (The reason for this comment is to prompt a more focused question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the math module is much faster, for example:

```
import math
def primefactors(n):
   #even number divisible
   while n % 2 == 0:
      print (2),
      n = n / 2
    
   #n became odd
   for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
     
      while (n % i == 0):
         print (i)
         n = n / i
    
   if n > 2:
      print (n)
 
n = int(input("Enter the number for calculating the prime factors :\n"))
primefactors(n)
```

An explanation of this is at: https://www.pythonpool.com/prime-factorization-python/

Comment: You can dump off the `math` module and just use `n**0.5`.  Additionally, the solution needs to create a list of prime factors, rather than just printing them.